# Touchscreen driver for Shuttle X50V4 AIO computer

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

I've searched high and low and can't find how to get a driver for the touch screen. The point was to make this a wall mounted computer so this is needed. I ran `lsusb` and it's listed but otherwise doesn't show up in the **Additional Drivers** menu. The device type is D-Wav Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax Touch Screen

Answer (score 0):

This eGalaxTouch page offers drivers to download for these devices, including for Linux: https://www.eeti.com/drivers_Linux.html